# Not seeing frames in WebStorm 2018.1 on Mac OS while debugging Node app

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am debugging a node app from WebStorm. I followed the instructions on [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html) page. My node app forks off other processes using the cluster module. The webpage says:

> **Node.js multiprocess debugging**
>
> WebStorm supports debugging additional Node.js processes that are
>   launched by the child_process.fork() method or by the cluster module.
>   Such processes are shown as threads in the Frame pane on the Debugger
>   tab of the Debug Tool Window.

But when I go to the Frames pane in WebStorm I do not see any threads. Instead I see the following:

[image]

How can I fix this? I am using WebStorm 2018.1 on Mac OS

[image]

Comment: did you set any breakpoints? Frames are only available when execution is suspended on breakpoint

Comment: yes I have set breakpoints but they never get hit. I do not see the checkmark against the breakpoint. That means they will not be hit. I also tried attaching webstorm to the child process but that also does not work - it is not able to connect.

Comment: I should clarify that its the breakpoints in the child process that are never hit. If I set breakpoints in the main process they do get hit and I also see frames. But its the child process code that I need to debug.

Comment: I think we should close or delete this question as the frames do show up when the breakpoints are hit. The WebStorm documentation is not clear and reading the documentation I understood the frames will be shown while app is running and I can select the frame corresponding to the child process that I want to debug. But it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I see. As for breakpoints in child process, make sure that it is spawned with debug options (`--inspect-brk`), debugging won't work otherwise

Comment: The child process is spawned with --debug. we are using version 0.10 of node

Comment: that's the issue. Node 0.10 is very old, and it's not supported anymore. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27150#focus=streamItem-27-2202820-0-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging child processes with **Node.js** *0.10* is not supported in recent IDE versions. Please consider upgrading **Node.js** to *0.12.x* or higher, child processes can be debugged there.
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27150#focus=streamItem-27-2202820-0-0